# App crash when implement google playservice

Tags: android-studio, gradle

When I insert implementation of google play service ad to gradle, then My app got crashed.. and my dependencies looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got those and imported ...

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
implementation'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

After implementing `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'`, you must also insert the following into your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For more information about `App ID (a-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713)` refer to https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start.

```
<application
...
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
     android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
...
</application>
```